# How to use CollectionSerializer in FastJson API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm updating the API code to FastJson (https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi) in where I work. The "old" code is using ActiveModel and has 
`ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new`. I have no idea how to "translate" this code to FastJson API.

I already searched in FastJson documentation about Collection Serialization (https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi#collection-serialization), but i didnt understand the example.

```rb
class API::Messages::MessagesSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description

  attribute :chats do
    ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(
      object.user_chats, serializer: API:Messages::ChatUserSerializer
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: Your response will be change in fast json API

Answer (score 0):

When collection will be passed in serializer it'll deal that collection perfectly no need to configure anything extra. Following are the serializers

```
class API::Messages::MessagesSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description

  attributes :chats do |message|
    API::Messages::ChatsSerializer.new(message. user_chats)
  end
end

class API::Messages::ChatsSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes ... # add attribute/logic as you want for single chat object
end
```

And your controller will be something like this

```
def show
  render json: API::Messages::MessagesSerializer.new(@message).serialized_json, status: :ok
end
```